# Automatically end self closing tag in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I get the below response from my service . I need to automatically add a self closing tag to it to structure my DOM.

How can I achieve this in Jquery or Angular JS.

```
Input :
      <link><br><br><b>Hello .This is my input

Output :  
      <link><br><br><b>Hello .This is my input</b></link>
```

Start input tags can be any, therefore I cannot add explicit logic for link and bold tags.

Your inputs are appreciated.

Comment: People who are downvoting either don't understand the  requirement or have never read the question.. post your comment when you downvote or your feedback

Answer (score 0):

try using "angular.element". This will take care of closing tag automatically.
Example:

```
angular.element("<b>").text("Hello .This is my input")
```

Comment: if we are not sure of the start tag .. in that case how could we use the above Thanks ....

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using DomParser. The exact levels of closing tags can be achieved using xml type.

```
var dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(i, "text/xml");
var removeParserErrorElem = dom.childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName("parsererror")[0];
dom.childNodes[0].removeChild(removeParserErrorElem);
```

The html will be in: `dom.childNodes[0];`

but it will also make br tags as opening and closing, you will have to handle that in some logic.

Give this one a try [Jquery Clean](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-clean/)

EDIT: If you get the OuterHTML, you will get the html. but for `<br />` tags for example, it returns `<br>` opening tag and `</br>` closing tag.

```
var target = dom.childNodes[0].outerHTML; //this returns the fixed html with impreper BR tags.
target.split("</br>").join("");
target.split("<br>").join("<br />"); // target now has the fixed HTML.
```

Comment: @Trin modified the answer.